# On pressed touch Hide/Show UIImage, and count number down from 10 to 0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

1. On every pressed touch I want UILabel to count number down one by one from 10 to 0.
2. Also when pressed I want to show UIImageView: "MyRocketWith", and when release the pressed touch I want to show UIImageView: "MyRocket".

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MyRocket: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var MyRocketWith: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Countdown: UILabel!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: UITouch? = touches.first
        if touch?.view != self.MyRocket {
            self.MyRocketWith.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code shows and hides the `UIImageView` on click of `UILabel`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MyRocketWith: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CountDownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MyRocket: UIImageView!
    var count = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
               CountDownLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
               CountDownLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        MyRocket.isHidden = false
        MyRocketWith.isHidden = true
        MyRocketWith.tag=0
    }

    @IBAction func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
        count = count-1
        CountDownLabel.text = String(count)

        if MyRocketWith.tag == 0
        {
            MyRocket.isHidden = true
            MyRocketWith.isHidden = false
            MyRocketWith.tag=1
        }
        else
        {
            MyRocket.isHidden = false
            MyRocketWith.isHidden = true
            MyRocketWith.tag=0
        }
    }
}
```